# Set document.title to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just a quickie..

If I set on an alert document.title to "ALERT" per say.
Then want to set it back afterwards is there an ezmode way to do this or will it be setting an ID on the link tags to set the title back to the ID. Note its an external script that is used on 20+ pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear because it starts talking about links and such. But you do specifically mention `document.title`, so...

If you set `document.title`, there's no way to set it back to its previous value without your saving the previous value and then restoring it, e.g.:

```
// Setting the value originally, remember the previous value first:
document.previousTitle = document.title;
document.title = "Testing 1 2 3";

// Restoring the previous title:
document.title = document.previousTitle;
document.previousTitle = undefined;
```

(Ideally, instead of clearing the `previousTitle` with `document.previousTitle = undefined;`, we'd use `delete document.previousTitle;`, but sadly that breaks on IE because `document` isn't *really* a JavaScript object, it just behaves very much like one, mostly.)

You might think: Let's go find the `title` element in the `head` and use its original content to restore the title. (That's what I thought.) But no, setting `document.title` actually *updates* the content of the `title` element in the `head`, so that doesn't work. You have to save the original somewhere else.

Comment: Nice answer you understood my vague question well :). Yes I see what you mean but that probably is the easiest way to go about it. Thanks.